# Split a file line by line and see if any words in the split file is in another file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to match a file with another file to see if any words in the first file(set1) is in any documents in my directory.

#### Code:

```
import glob
import re
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
import nltk


folder_path = "/home/#"
file_pattern = "/*.txt"


corpus_root = "/home/#" 
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*') 
wordlists.fileids()
set1=set(wordlists.words('locations.txt'))
set2=set(wordlists.words('names.txt'))


match_list = []

folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern)

for file in folder_contents:
    read_file = open(file, 'rt').read()
    if set1 in read_file:
        match_list.append(file)
        print(file)
```

#### Output:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-c63210fee01a> in <module>()
     23     read_file = open(file, 'rt').read()
     24     words=read_file.split()
---> 25     if set1 in read_file:
     26         match_list.append(file)
     27         print(file)

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not set
```

Is there anyway to see if set1 is in any of the files in my directory?

Comment: Why are you not using `wordlists.words('names.txt')` for reading files from the directory

Comment: For sample sake. I will be using it when i do my official code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the `read_file` content into a set, and try doing a `set.intersection()`:

```
for file in folder_contents:
    read_file = open(file, 'rt').read()
    if set1.intersection(set(read_file.split(" "))):
        match_list.append(file)
        print(file)
```

Comment: Just did it. Thanks again.